# Reactjs: Fetch data from API using helper class and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm beginner for Reactjs and trying to improve myself with a project. As progressing with my project, I now need to setup a structure such that my UI component will connect to some REST API, and use the returned data. This has many examples on the internet and fine.

My question is, if and how I could separate the API connection from the actual UI components. I believe it could be good, as I would have the chance to reuse the API connection functions within various UI components. (It would be ideal to do the common tasks related with API connections within these helper methods.)

For that, I created a PrimaryForm.js file, that is the UI component. And for API calls, I created an APIManager.js file. Ideally, APIManager should not have any jsx, but only functions that return API call results to the PrimaryForm.js.

I am sharing the code I wrote so far, to achieve that.

PrimaryForm.js, that deletages the API call to APIManager.js (see handleTestConnection part below):

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import {Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import PrimaryFormValidator from '../../validators/PrimaryFormValidator'
import styles from '../../Styles';

import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel';
import BackIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIosRounded';
import TestIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Power';
import ForwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForwardIosRounded';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import APIManager from '../../managers/APIManager';

function PrimaryForm(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);}, []);

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    hostname: {
      value: "test",
      isError: false,
      errorText: "",
    },
    serverIp: {
      value: "192.168.16.1",
      isError: false,
      errorText: "",
    },
    osVariant: {
      value: "Linux",
      isError: false,
      errorText: "",
    },
    databaseSid: {
      value: "mysql",
      isError: false,
      errorText: "",
    },
    listenerPort: {
      value: "3306",
      isError: false,
      errorText: "",
    },
    isFormValid: true,
    isPrimaryDbValid: false,
  });

  const evaluateFormValid = (prevState) => {
    return ((prevState.hostname.value!=="" && !prevState.hostname.isError) &&
            (prevState.serverIp.value!=="" && !prevState.serverIp.isError) &&
            (prevState.osVariant.value!=="" && !prevState.osVariant.isError) &&
            (prevState.databaseSid.value!=="" && !prevState.databaseSid.isError) &&
            (prevState.listenerPort.value!=="" && !prevState.listenerPort.isError));
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    var valResult;
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'hostname':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateHostname(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        setState({
          ...state,
          hostname:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          },
        });
        break;
      case 'serverIp':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateIpAddress(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        setState({
          ...state,
          serverIp:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'databaseSid':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateDatabaseSid(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        setState({
          ...state,
          databaseSid:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'listenerPort':
        valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateListenerPort(event.target.value, event.target.labels[0].textContent);
        setState({
          ...state,
          listenerPort:
          {
            value: event.target.value,
            isError: valResult.isError,
            errorText: valResult.errorText,
          }
        });
        break;
      default:
        //setState({...state,});
    }
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isFormValid: evaluateFormValid(prevState),
    }));
  }

  const handleTestConnection = event => {
    APIManager.testConnection(state.hostname.value, state.serverIp.value, state.osVariant.value, state.databaseSid.value, state.listenerPort.value);
    //console.log("Data:" + APIManager.state.testConnectionResult);
  }

  const handleSelect = osVariant => event => {
    var valResult = PrimaryFormValidator.validateOsVariant(event.target.value, inputLabel.current.textContent);
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      osVariant:
      {
        value: event.target.value,
        isError: valResult.isError,
        errorText: valResult.errorText,
      },
    }));
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isFormValid: evaluateFormValid(prevState),
  }));
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={classes.bigContainer}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <Typography variant="subtitle1" gutterBottom className={classes.subtitle1} color='secondary'>
                Primary Database System
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Information related with the primary database system. Please note that the primary database has to be up and running.
              </Typography>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.bigContainer}>
              <form className={classes.formArea}>
                <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                  id="hostname"
                  label="FQDN Hostname *"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={state.hostname.value}
                  error={state.hostname.isError}
                  helperText={state.hostname.errorText}
                  variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                  id="serverIp"
                  label="Server Ip Address *"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={state.serverIp.value}
                  error={state.serverIp.isError}
                  helperText={state.serverIp.errorText}
                  variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                  <InputLabel id="osVarLabel" htmlFor="osVariant" ref={inputLabel}>OS Variant *</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    id="osVariant"
                    label="OS Variant *"
                    value={state.osVariant.value}
                    error={state.osVariant.isError}
                    onChange={handleSelect("osVariant")}
                    input={<OutlinedInput id="outlinedinput" labelWidth={labelWidth}/>}>
                    <MenuItem value={''}></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={'Linux'}>Linux</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={'Windows'}>Windows</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                  <FormHelperText error={state.osVariant.isError} hidden={!state.osVariant.isError}>
                    {state.osVariant.errorText}
                  </FormHelperText>
                </FormControl>
                <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                  id="databaseSid"
                  label="Database SID"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={state.databaseSid.value}
                  error={state.databaseSid.isError}
                  helperText={state.databaseSid.errorText}
                  variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                  id="listenerPort"
                  label="Listener Port"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={state.listenerPort.value}
                  error={state.listenerPort.isError}
                  helperText={state.listenerPort.errorText}
                  variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" />
                {/* <TextField className={classes.formControl}
                  disabled={true}
                  id="isFormValid"
                  label="Is Form Valid Now?"
                  value={state.isFormValid}
                  variant="outlined" autoComplete="off" /> */}
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>      
        </Paper>
        <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <div className={classes.flexBar}>
                  <Tooltip title="Back to previous step">
                    <div>
                      <Button variant="contained"
                        disabled={true}
                        className={classes.actionButton}
                        size='large'>
                        <BackIcon className={classes.rightIcon}/>Back
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </Tooltip>

                  <Tooltip title="Test Connection">
                    <div>
                      <Button variant="contained" className={classes.actionButton}
                        color="primary"
                        size='large'
                        disabled={!state.isFormValid}
                        onClick={handleTestConnection}>
                        <TestIcon className={classes.rightIcon}/>Test
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </Tooltip>

                  <Tooltip title="Proceed the next step">
                    <div>
                      <Button
                        variant="contained" className={classes.actionButton}
                        color="primary"
                        size='large'
                        disabled={!state.isPrimaryDbValid}>
                        <ForwardIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />Next
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </Tooltip>

                  <Tooltip title="Cancel creating new configuration">
                    <Button variant="contained" color="default" className={classes.actionButton}
                      component={Link} to={'/configs'} style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                      <CancelIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />Cancel
                      </Button>
                  </Tooltip>
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(PrimaryForm));
```

And here is my APIManager.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class APIManager extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props); 
      this.state = {
        testConnectionResult: {},
        ...this.props,
      }
      this.testConnection = this.testConnection.bind(this);
    }

    static testConnection(hostname, serverIp, osVariant, databaseSid, listenerPort) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api?objtype=ConnectionDef&hostname=${hostname}&serverIp=${serverIp}&osVariant=${osVariant}&databaseSid=${databaseSid}&listenerPort=${listenerPort}`)
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(result => this.setState({testConnectionResult: result}));
        //.catch((error) => console.error(error));
       console.log("Data:" + this.testConnectionResult);

      return this.testConnectionResult;
    }
}
```

Now I could not solve getting below error:

> APIManager.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.setState is
>   not a function
>       at APIManager.js:16

I guess I'm struggling now to pass the result taken from API call to the external (callee) class / function.

I Googled, also checked other questions on Stackoverflow with this error, but that really didn't help me figure out the issue. I also wanted to ask if I'm making a principal mistake.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to create a component just to hold API call logic. in react components are used to declare visual stuff(so they will have jsx).

If you want to extract api call logic out of component, you can put that logic in some function which returns a promise. like so:

```
function testApi(...args) {
  return fetch(/* url parms */)
}
```

then in your component, on some event say click you can make API call and set response data to component state to change view:

```
handleTestEvent(...args) {
  testApi(...args)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({testConnectionResult: result}));
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error));
      this.setState({testConnectionResult: []});
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any added value in this anwer. Why would I write an extra function just not to write one line "fetch"? Doesn't make a good sense.

Comment: `testApi` can be used across different components. it would have any api specific logic like validation, creating get url etc. which you won't have to repeat each time. you can move catch and parsing stuff like `.then(response => response.json())` into this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `this` (an instance context) from a static method. Make it a regular instance method and it should work.

Comment: Hi Alan, I removed the static keyword in my testConnection function. Now I get below error and couldn't figure out why: Uncaught TypeError: _managers_APIManager__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_23__.default.testConnection is not a function
    at handleTestConnection (PrimaryForm.js:130)

Comment: Can you post your usage of this class? It's hard to tell without that :)

Comment: how do you mean? You want to see the whole code of caller class, PrimaryForm.js? Actually it's not a class as I had to use some hooks, but if you want to see, I'm updating the question with the whole code of PrimaryForm.js. :)